# Determine button object that invokes a common event handler shared by a list of buttons?

Tags: python

If we have a list of button objects declared in a program with just a single common event handler, how can we determine which particular button is invoking the handler?

My code is as follows:

```
self.bttn = []
        for i in range(0, 10, 1):
            self.bttn.append(Button(self,
                                    text = str(i),
                                     command = self.callback).grid(row = 4, column = i + 1, sticky = E))
```

Comment: More information needed. What framework is this? What is Button?

Comment: Looks like Tkinter to me.

Answer (score 0):

I like to pass an argument to the callback that's unique to the button. In this case, you could use the button's index. (although you'll have to be careful to invoke "early binding" behavior by using it in a default argument in the lambda; otherwise `i` will always have the last value that `i` contained, rather than the value it had when you created the button.)

```
for i in range(0, 10, 1):
    self.bttn.append(
        Button(
            self,
            text = str(i),
            command = lambda i=i: self.callback(i)
        ).grid(row = 4, column = i + 1, sticky = E)
    )

#later on in the class...    
def callback(self, idx):
    print "button #{} was clicked".format(idx)
```

By the way, your `self.bttn` list will contain only `None` values, because `None` is the result of `Button.grid()`. If you want `self.bttn` to contain buttons, you have to create the button, add it to the list, and grid it separately.

```
for i in range(0, 10, 1):
    b = Button(
        self,
        text = str(i),
        command = lambda i=i: self.callback(i)
    )
    b.grid(row = 4, column = i + 1, sticky = E)
    self.bttn.append(b)
```